# Chrome not Printing?

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

I have printer stylesheet setup on my site. It works in all browsers but Chrome. Chrome shows nothing in the print preview and when I attempt to print Chrome prints nothing. If I remove the print stylesheet and click print it shows the entire page *including* hidden portions of the page that should not display. Not sure what to do or why it is not working.

Have others seen this behavior? What can I do? What code do you need to see?

Here is the way the print stylesheet is called if something is wrong?

```
<link href="print.css" media="print" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: what google chrome's version are you using?

Comment: @Pabloker - The latest release version. Version 20.

Comment: There is a bug with Google Chrome's print preview http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101550. Try this: press ctrl + shift + P to use system print dialog instead to print preview.

Comment: @Pabloker - Attempting that just spit out a blank page from the printer.

Comment: Try to comment some lines of `print.css`, and check the results. Maybe you can find where the problem is.

Comment: @Pabloker - I am sorry I do not follow, what do you mean by comment some lines of print.css?  This?: `/* Comment */`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13423/discussion-between-pabloker-and-lynda)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appeared to have been a caching issue. Once I refreshed the cache and corrected earlier errors the issue resolved itself.

Comment: What cache? I have the same problem!